# Detect when element is dragged near the sides of the window and perform function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm using jQuery UI's `draggable` method to drag a panel around the screen. I want to be able to replicate a function in Photoshop, where you can drag a panel near the edge of the screen and it will display a glowing bar along the edge to indicate that it will attach there (while hovering over it in the mouse down state), and when you drop the panel it transforms in to a full-height sticky panel that is attached to the edge you dropped it on.

Can anyone help achieve this in HTML/JS?

If someone can just help me detect when I'm say within 10px of the right side of the screen *while in the drag/`start` state*, I can probably handle the rest.

Comment: Perhaps I would be able to create an element that was 10px wide and spanned 100% of the height of the page, made it transparent with `pointer-events:none`, and then attached the `droppable` jQuery UI method to it I would be able to only accept panel drops and perform an action such as changing the height of the panel to 100%? That way there's an element there to accept the drop, but since there's no pointer events it can't be accessible with the mouse? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concept seems to be legit! keeping an element to accept the droppable is what I first had in my mind! So the trick is nice.

```
$("droppable-element").droppable(function(){
    accept:'draggable-element',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        (this).css("change the CSS of the element inside this. probably pointer-events");
        //do the rest of the coding here. Probably the event handling when the dragged element is dropped.
    }
});
```

In the above code, change the appropriate css style in order to gain back the mouse accessibility.